# Seaborn heatmap with numerical axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I want to overlay a heatmap with a second chart (a KDEplot, but for this example I'll use a scatterplot, since it shows the same issue).

Seaborn heatmaps have categorical axes, so overlaying a chart with numerical axes doesn't line up the two charts properly.

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({2:[1,2,3],4:[1,3,5],6:[2,4,6]}, index=[3,6,9])
df

    2   4   6
3   1   1   2
6   2   3   4
9   3   5   6

fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
sb.heatmap(df, ax=ax1, alpha=0.1)
```

[image]

Overlaying this with a scatterplot:

```
fig, ax1 = plt.subplots(1,1)
sb.heatmap(df, ax=ax1, alpha=0.1)
ax1.scatter(x=5,y=5, s=100)
ax1.set_xlim(0,10)
ax1.set_ylim(0,10)
```

Is there a way to convince the heatmap to use the column and index values as numerical values?

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You cannot "convince" `heatmap` not to produce a categorical plot. Best use another image plot, which uses numerical axes. For example, use a `pcolormesh` plot. The assumption is of course that the columns and rows are equally spread. Then,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df = pd.DataFrame({2:[1,2,3],4:[1,3,5],6:[2,4,6]}, index=[3,6,9])

c = np.array(df.columns)
x = np.concatenate((c,[c[-1]+np.diff(c)[-1]]))-np.diff(c)[-1]/2.
r = np.array(df.index)
y = np.concatenate((r,[r[-1]+np.diff(r)[-1]]))-np.diff(r)[-1]/2.
X,Y = np.meshgrid(x,y)


fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1)
pc = ax.pcolormesh(X,Y,df.values, alpha=0.5, cmap="magma")
fig.colorbar(pc)
ax.scatter(x=5,y=5, s=100)
ax.set_xlim(0,10)
ax.set_ylim(0,10)

plt.show()
```

produces

[image]

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I've been using pcolormesh but there are aspects of seaborn's heatmap that I prefer.

Comment: Since a seaborn heatmap is nothing else than a `pcolormesh` plot, there shouldn't be any difference. In case you need something specific in your heatmap, it may make sense to ask specifically about this desired feature.

Comment: There are a few things I wanted but mainly I find the seaborn call much more obvious than going through the np.meshgrid preparation for pcolormesh, which I find confusing (I tend to end up with reversed axes)

Comment: You can use `ax.invert_yaxis()`, if that is what you mean.

Comment: I just mean that the setup for pcolormesh is much more elaborate than a s simple `heatmap(df)` from seaborn and offers more ways to get disoriented. Since sb.heatmap is just a call to pcolomesh, and pcolormesh gives numerical axes, I thought there might be a way to keep seaboard's simplicity and get the pcolormesh behavior I wanted. If there's not, I'll just keep on using pcolormesh.

Comment: Internally seaborn heatmap creates a pcolormesh with a meshgrid, like `np.meshgrid(np.arange(n),np.arange(m))` with `n` and `m` being the number of rows and columns of the pivoted data, it then sets the labels to the actual row and column index. So heatmap is much simpler indeed, because it does not have to deal with the actual numeric values of the data.