# Plotting vertical and horizontal lines inside a seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

I had some data on which I had to do some image processing to obtain the centers of the 4 'circles' (refer figure). I was able to do that correctly using the Blob detection function of the OpenCV library in Python.

I want to plot the lines perpendicular to the x and y axis to indicate these centers on the seaborn heatmap output. I'm unable to do so. I have the co-ordinates for the lines in a separate list.

But I'm unable to plot even one line to begin with.

```
plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
sns.heatmap(df_scaled)
plt.axvline(x = -10.86,color='white',linewidth=2) # For now let's assume value of x as -10.86
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()]
```

[image: Seaborn Heatmap]

Comment: You could try to change the z-order: `plt.axvline(..., zorder=3) `. But the real problem might be that the axes are categorical, with textual labels while internally they are numbers 0,1,2,..... Showing the contents of a small part of `df_scaled` (as text, not as image) could help shed some light.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49020709/seaborn-heatmap-with-numerical-axes) talks about seaborn always forcing categorical axes and some ways to work around it.

Comment: That works @JohanC. Thanks. Will update the thread with the answer